# I want to change my ban command to not ban any staff members discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to be able to change this code to where staff cannot ban staff regardless of position and not go off higher roles like admins can't ban mods. I tried to tie it to the staff role but the bot does not send an output.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, user, *, reason: commands.clean_content = '[No reason given]'):
    """ Ban a user from the current guild. """
    author = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = await self.fetch_user(ctx, user)
    if guild.get_member(user.id) and (guild.get_member(user.id).top_role.position >= guild.me.top_role.position): >This is where heirarchy comes into play
        raise GenericCustomException(
            "Sorry, but I can not ban that user. Maybe try checking my role hierarchy?"
        )
    else:  # this is where I try to pass the mod role to be ignored from banning each other
        if discord.utils.get(user.roles, id=<insert mod role id here>):
            return await ctx.send("you cannot ban a staff member")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try searching if the user has a certain permission that one of your roles have, then if true, send the message. For example, if I wanted to see if the user had `ban_members` permissions:

```
if user.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    return await ctx.send("you cannot ban a staff member")
```

Make sure to replace `ban_members` with any other permission that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the roles of the user and check if he has a role in a list of mod roles. I prefer to use the role IDs since it can't be changed.

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, user, *, reason: commands.clean_content = '[No reason given]'):
    """ Ban a user from the current guild. """
    author = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = await self.fetch_user(ctx, user)
    if guild.get_member(user.id) and (guild.get_member(user.id).top_role.position >= guild.me.top_role.position): >This is where heirarchy comes into play
        raise GenericCustomException(
            "Sorry, but I can not ban that user. Maybe try checking my role hierarchy?"
        )
    else:
        whitelisted_roles = [123456, 456789, 789012] # List of Mod roles 
        for role in user.roles:
            if role.id in whitelisted_roles:
                return await ctx.send("You can't ban this user! He is a moderator!")
        else:
            # ban the user
            pass
```